# Custom service exits with status code 216/GROUP on RHEL 8.6 but works on 8.8

Tags: systemd

I have a custom user service with the following unit file:

```
[Unit]
Description=<DESC>
After=podman.socket
Requires=podman.socket


[Service]
Environment=DOCKER_HOST=unix:///run/user/$UID/podman/podman.sock
TimeoutStartSec=0
ExecStart=/usr/bin/<BINARY_NAME>
Restart=always
Type=notify
NotifyAccess=all
User=<User>

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Which on RHEL 8.8 works perfectly fine, but on rhel 8.6 gives Exited with error code, where the code is 216/group.
Both the user and the group exists.

The service file is placed in `/etc/systemd/user` and I start the server with `systemctl enable --user --now <SERVICENAME>`.
I run `systemctl --user daemon-reload`, before I try to enable the service.

I have tried to run the binary on the system and it works.
I got as far as trying to change the `WantedBy` to `default.target` but that was no success either.

I have had to make certain things generic due to confidentiality reasons.

I have looked at many potential solutions in this forum, but I couldn't get any of them to work.

- Tried changing type to: exec
- Tried changing type to: simple
- Tried to add group with the users group
- Tried changing type to: Fork

Comment: When you say "the group exists", what group? I don't see one specified in the unit file; did you mean the user's primary group?

Comment: If you are placing it in `/etc/systemd/user` and starting it in userspace. Why define the user in the service then?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I tried to add `Group=<DEFAULT USER GROUP>` to the file.

Comment: @FelixJN I was told it was needed? is this incorrect?

Comment: @LarsNielsen it depends on who is starting the service. Any user or `root` but it should be run as `user=john`, `group=johnnies`? Then specify. Otherwise the default is that it is run with user/group of the one starting it. Hence I wonder, why you provide it as a user service in the first place - if this is a service the server provides, let's take the example of a web server, `root` should start it but with user/group set to `www-data`. If this is a service any user should be able to start for himself, do not set it.

Comment: On at least systemd 253 there is no variable substitution taking place here `Environment=DOCKER_HOST=unix:///run/user/$UID/podman/podman.sock`    In other words `$UID` is not replaced by the number.  Also you might need to add `Requires=user@1114.service
After=user@1114.service` (Replace 1114 with the UID)

Comment: Thank you @FelixJN this solved the problem!

Comment: @FelixJN would you write your comment up as a proper Answer? Thanks!